# How to conditionally extract values from a list using two other lists?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have three lists as follows:

```
a = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
b = [3, 3, 4, 4, 6]
c = [1983, 2401, 852, 2442, 5035]
```

I used:

```
x = [x for x in a if x in b]
```

which gives me `[3,4]` from list a. I need corresponding values from list c which will be `[852,5035]`. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Please let me know the reason for the downvote. It would be helpful for me to improve my questions in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = [c_val for a_val, c_val in zip(a, c) if a_val in b]
```

Use `zip` to get the elements of `c` corresponding to each element of `a`. Note that if `b` is big, it may be better to use a `set`, which does `in` much faster:

```
b_set = set(b)
x = [c_val for a_val, c_val in zip(a, c) if a_val in b_set]
```

Don't put the `set` call in the list comprehension, though; that would recompute the set on every iteration, ruining any performance benefits.

Comment: I like the one liner and it worked as I need. Thanks.